# Blackberry EventInjector (alt + esc key) is not working on 7.0 and 7.1 devices

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

In my blackberry application i am using EventInjector for implementing switch application menu (alt + escape key). The following code are used in my application.

```
EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent eiK= new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent(EventInjector.KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN,Characters.ESCAPE,KeypadListener.STATUS_ALT);
```

The above code is working fine on 4.3, 4.7, 5.0 and 6.0 devices. But its not working on 7.0, 7.1 devices and simulators.

Any idea about this?

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: Try adding `Thread.sleep` here and there, sometimes it works. The general rule is: if the event is being ignored, sometimes a little pause before it (or between several events) works.

Comment: no luck, its not working

Comment: any idea about this issue? Still its not working for me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either, on 7.x.  Remember that invoking actions like bringing up the Application Switcher, by injecting keystrokes, is kind of a *hack*.  If BlackBerry really wanted you to do this, they would have added an API.  So, unfortunately, it's not surprising if this kind of technique stops working at some point.  That said, it certainly could be possible another way, or slightly changing the timing, as Mister Smith suggests.  You also might need to inject `KeyEvent.KEY_UP` events, too, not just key down events.

Comment: Find out what global events does this combination generate and try to generate events with the same event uids. Make a simple global event logger to check that.

Comment: Event ejection requires a permission to be set (saying this just in case you have missed this point).